Change password on ESXi with REST API
I am trying to write a script in PHP that resets the root password on an ESXi "myhost". I have the old password in $oldpass and the new password in $newpass. The host for my tests is a brand new deployment of a nested ESXi 8.0.2b.
I've been on it for several months, already...
I'm not so sure where the problem comes from after trying so many things, including an AI... that kept apologizing.
From what I gathered, the only way to do so is via a SOAP call directly to the ESXi, authenticating as root to the SOAP broker:
I tried with a SOAPClient object, here's the code:
class ESXI_SOAP extends SoapClient {
private $ServiceInstance;
private $session;
 
public function __construct( $url , $user , $pass ) {
  try {
   parent::__construct( $url . '/vimService.wsdl' ,
    [ 'trace'      => true
    , 'exceptions' => true
    , "location"   => $url
    , 'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
       [ 'ssl' => [ 'verify_peer' => false
       , 'verify_peer_name' => false , 'allow_self_signed' => true ]
       ]
      )
    ]
   ) ;

   $this->ServiceInstance =
    $this->RetrieveServiceContent(
     [ "_this" => new SoapVar( "ServiceInstance", XSD_STRING , "ServiceInstance" ) ]
    )->returnval ;

   $this->session =
    $this->Login(
     [ '_this'    => $this->ServiceInstance->sessionManager
     , 'userName' => $user
     , 'password' => $pass
     ]
    )->returnval ;
   echo "login successful\n\nServiceInstance:\n" ;
   var_dump($this->ServiceInstance);
   echo "\nSession:\n";
   var_dump( $this->session ) ;
  } catch( Exception $e ) {
   printf("%sn",$e->__toString() ) ;
   return false ;
  }

  echo $this->__getLastResponseHeaders();

  /*** Logout ***/
  try{
   echo "attempting logout()\n";
   $result = $this->Logout(
    [ "_this" => $this->ServiceInstance
    ]
   ) ;
  } catch (Exception $e) {
   printf("%sn",$e->__toString());
   return false;
  }
  echo "logout successful\n";
}

The login is successful, but it seems to timeout immediately, so the Session object is unusable, even for an immediate logout:
login successful

ServiceInstance:
object(stdClass)#4 (26) {
  (...)
  ["about"]=>
  object(stdClass)#8 (14) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(11) "VMware ESXi"
    ["fullName"]=>
    string(32) "VMware ESXi 7.0.3 build-20328353"
    ["vendor"]=>
    string(12) "VMware, Inc."
    ["version"]=>
    string(5) "7.0.3"
    ["patchLevel"]=>
    string(4) "0.55"
    ["build"]=>
    string(8) "20328353"
    ["localeVersion"]=>
    string(4) "INTL"
    ["localeBuild"]=>
    string(3) "000"
    ["osType"]=>
    string(9) "vmnix-x86"
    ["productLineId"]=>
    string(11) "embeddedEsx"
    ["apiType"]=>
    string(9) "HostAgent"
    ["apiVersion"]=>
    string(7) "7.0.3.0"
    ["licenseProductName"]=>
    string(17) "VMware ESX Server"
    ["licenseProductVersion"]=>
    string(3) "7.0"
  }
(...)
}
 
Session:
object(stdClass)#2 (11) {
  ["key"]=>string(36) "5223f016-7f92-c38c-0870-6fb25219ef71"
  ["userName"]=>string(4) "root"
  ["fullName"]=>string(13) "Administrator"
  ["loginTime"]=>string(27) "2024-07-11T19:26:13.116449Z"
  ["lastActiveTime"]=>string(27) "2024-07-11T19:26:13.116466Z"
  ["locale"]=>string(2) "en"
  ["messageLocale"]=>string(2) "en"
 ["extensionSession"]=>bool(false)
  ["ipAddress"]=>string(10) "(redacted)"
  ["userAgent"]=>string(26) "PHP-SOAP/7.4.3-4ubuntu2.23"
  ["callCount"]=>int(0)
}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2024 19:26:13 GMT
Set-Cookie: vmware_soap_session="4f71046b2b4285b476a11ca548f61a690bba1a89"; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure;
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 815

attempting logout()
SoapFault exception: [ServerFaultCode] The object 'vmodl.ManagedObject:' has already been deleted or has not been completely created in /var/www/html/interfaces/RootPasswordChange/SOAP.php:45
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/interfaces/RootPasswordChange/SOAP.php(45): SoapClient->__call()
#1 /var/www/html/interfaces/RootPasswordChange/SOAP.php(73): ESXI_SOAP->__construct()
#2 /var/www/html/interfaces/RootPasswordChange/SOAP.php(90): ESXI_Test()

This one was based on a script found on Stack Overflow that exhibits the same symptoms on my system.
It's like I'm missing something in storing the $ServiceInstance or passing it to Logout.
At this stage, I'm just looking for a working $this->Logout().

"the login is successful, but it seems to timeout immediately" - Is there a session cookie, and if so are you keeping track of it? I can't quite tell from the code.

No there is no session cookie. I couldn't find the cookie key, I tried to add a cookie named "key", "vmware-api-session-id":
$this->__setCookie("vmware-api-session-id",$this->session->key)
but nothing work, so I removed the cookie. Anyway, no other code I could find does anything with cookies, it's like the session is persistent only with $this->session coming from the successful login with $this->session = $this->getSession($this->ServiceInstance,$user,$pass). I looked at the source code of the VMwar API but didn't notice any cookie anyhow.

Is this the API you are using? I see nothing in there to change a password.

To be clear, I' trying to do the same as in this PowerCLI code but in PHP. I'd prefer cURL, but anything is fine. When I'm talking about API, it's the vCloud SDK for PHP or anything similar: despite RTFM, I can't figure out how to "use" it in my PHP scripts. As shown above, I'm using the RESTful API to login via cURL, or the Web Service broker to login via SOAP (supposedly PowerCLI's connect-viserver's way), but SOAP login expires immediately.

You're aware that both the links you provided are more than a decade old? Also IIRC changing the root password on the host will drop the connection to vCenter and you'll have to add the host again. It's been a while since I've done it so can't say for sure though.

Using ssh to connect and run the relevant commands might be your best bet

Unfortunately, ssh is not an option: it's disabled by company policy on all hosts. Also, all hosts are in (normal) lockdown mode.
Changing the root password does nothing to the connection between the vCenter and the ESXi, it's only used for the initial connection. Once the vpxa agent is installed on the ESXi, the vCenter doesn't use the root account any longer.
From what I read on the broadcom/vmware site, the only way is through SOAP, it doesn't seem to exist in the RESTful API. However, I can't figure out what's wrong in my connection code that gives me the "not authenticated" error.
